# Macos 10.14.3 wi-fi issue

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, macbook-pro, macos-mojave

I have macbook pro 2017 without ethernet. Today I found strange issue. I can see wi-fi connections, I can coonnect to my wi-fi router. But safari/chrome/opera doesn't work. Ping works, browser doesn't! Even git client works well.

Comment: Good practice to make answer on own question and mark it as accepted. It mark question as solved and give points to You.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by creating new wi-fi service in Settings->Networking